# Missing some variable declaration in java file when git Merge with another branch

Tags: java, git, github, merge, git-stash

I have two git branches and I merged these two branches together. One of the java class , some variable declarations are missing  .

### A branch

```
class Cal {

int x =10 ;
int y = 20 ;

public void m(){
system.out.print (x+y);
}}
```

### B branch

```
class Cal {

int a =10 ;
int b = 20 ;

public void m2(){
system.out.print (a+b);
}}
```

Branch A merged to Branch B

Then;

```
class Cal {

int a =10 ;
int b = 20 ;

public void m(){
system.out.print (x+y);
}

public void m2(){
system.out.print (a+b);
}

}
```

Any special reason to happen it ?.

Comment: Was that class merged automatically or were there conflicts you had to manually resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you probably modified the same lines in the two files, so you should have got a merge conflict. When you resolved the conflict, you should have done so such that the resultant code was correct. Git isn't smart enough to do that for you (if it were, I'de hire it and fire myself (boss man, are you reading?)). Read up [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts). When you do a merge, you should consider using the --no-commit flag to allow you to build the resultant merged code and ensure that it is correct before committing, or else you will need to correct the merge issues on the next commit (and possibly rebase/squash to clean up that mess before you push).

A not so flippant answer - when git finds that different lines of a file are modified in each of the merge candidates, it assumes that you want both and so "adds" the two changes together. But if you change the exact same line, then it really cant know how you want to handle this case. So it marks up the file with the git markup showing the two options and asks you to go in there and "resolve" the two to your satisfaction. Those are the funny <<<<<, =====, >>>> markers that you see in the file. Edit that by selecting one or the other or both or whatever to resolve the issue, then continue. When you did your merge, you may have just selected one set and not the other, and thats how you lost the other in the final merge.